# Unable to click a link in material UI drawer component using router

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a drawer component in my project. I have used the one from material UI however the problem is I cannot get it to link to my other pages after selecting an option. In the console I get the following errors, "Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use `<Link> outside a <Router>` at invariant" and "The above error occurred in the <Router.Consumer> component:"

[My front end with the error coming up after pressing an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWpL9.png)

I have created my router in my App.js file and I dont think the problem is there as it used to work with my bootstrap navigation bar.

I have tried a few things on trying to get this to work such as adding `onClick: () => history.push('/')`. This also didn't work for me as the history was undefined even though I set it like so `const history = useHistory();`.

I have also tried adding in the withRouter at the bottom of my DrawerComponent class and that didn't seem to work either.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import EnglishPremierLeague from "./Pages/EnglishPremierLeague";
import ItalySeriaA from "./Pages/ItalySerieA";
import GermanyBundesliga from "./Pages/GermanyBundesliga";
import FranceLigue1 from "./Pages/FranceLigue1";
import SpainLaLiga from "./Pages/SpainLaLiga";
import WorldCup from "./Pages/WorldCup";
import LeagueStandings from "./Pages/LeagueStandings";
import DrawerComponent from "./components/DrawerComponent";
import {makeStyles} from "@mui/styles";
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

const userStyles = makeStyles({
    container: {
        display: "flex"
    }
})

function App() {
    const classes = userStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.container}>
            <DrawerComponent/>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/EnglishPremierLeague" component={EnglishPremierLeague}/>
                    <Route path="/ItalySeriaA" component={ItalySeriaA}/>
                    <Route path="/GermanyBundesliga" component={GermanyBundesliga}/>
                    <Route path="/FranceLigue1" component={FranceLigue1}/>
                    <Route path="/SpainLaLiga" component={SpainLaLiga}/>
                    <Route path="/WorldCup" component={WorldCup}/>
                    <Route path="/LeagueStandings" component={LeagueStandings}/>
                </Switch>

            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

DrawerComponent.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import {Drawer} from "@mui/material";
import {styled, useTheme} from "@mui/material/styles";
import MuiAppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";


const drawerWidth = 240;

const Main = styled('main', {shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open'})(
    ({theme, open}) => ({
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(3),
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
        marginLeft: `-${drawerWidth}px`,
        ...(open && {
            transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
                easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
                duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
            }),
            marginLeft: 0,
        }),
    }),
);

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})(({theme, open}) => ({
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    ...(open && {
        width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
        marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}px`,
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
    }),
}));

const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({theme}) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
}));

const DrawerComponent = () => {

    const theme = useTheme();
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleDrawerClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    const history = useHistory();
    console.log(history)

    const itemList = [
        {
            text: "Home",
            icon: <InboxIcon/>,
            onClick: () => history.push('/')
        },
        {
            text: "English Premier League",
            onClick: () => history.push("/EnglishPremierLeague")

        },
        {
            text: "Standings",
            icon: <MailIcon/>

        },
        {
            text: "Fixtures"
        }
    ];

    return (
        <div>

            <Box sx={{display: 'flex'}}>
                <CssBaseline/>
                <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <IconButton
                            color="inherit"
                            aria-label="open drawer"
                            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
                            edge="start"
                            sx={{mr: 2, ...(open && {display: 'none'})}}
                        >
                            <MenuIcon/>
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
                            Football Finesse
                        </Typography>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <Drawer
                    sx={{
                        width: drawerWidth,
                        flexShrink: 0,
                        '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
                            width: drawerWidth,
                            boxSizing: 'border-box',
                        },
                    }}
                    variant="persistent"
                    anchor="left"
                    open={open}
                >
                    <DrawerHeader>
                        <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                            {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon/> : <ChevronRightIcon/>}
                        </IconButton>
                    </DrawerHeader>
                    <Divider/>
                    <List>

                        {itemList.map((item, index) => {

                            const {text, icon, onClick} = item;
                            return (
                                <ListItem button key={text} onClick={onClick}>

                                    {icon && <ListItemIcon>
                                        {icon}
                                    </ListItemIcon>}
                                    <ListItemText primary={text}/>
                                </ListItem>
                            )
                        })}
                    </List>
                    <Divider/>
                </Drawer>

                <Main open={open}>
                    <DrawerHeader/>

                </Main>
            </Box>
        </div>
    )
}
export default DrawerComponent;
```

P.S - I am very new to react so please dumb it down as much as possible, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<DrawerComponent />` needs to be inside the `<Router>` component

React Router is built in a way that requires many React Router component to be used inside of a Router component. This is because of how the components share data to each other